# Field length metadata in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: metadata, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to find metadata about the length of fields in MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 - does anyone know if/where this information is available from the metadata services? I tried looking on the AttributeMetadata class, but can't find anything there. Yet, the field length does show up in MS's metadata browser, so it must be accessible somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the attribute is a string or ntext attribute, you can cast the AttributeMetadata object over to a StringAttributeMetadata object, and that will have the maximum length of those fields.

Answer (score 1):

Thanx @Matt worked like a charm. I used it as below:

```
StringAttributeMetadata stringAttributeMetadata = (StringAttributeMetadata)attributeMetadata;
recordToBeUpdated[recordFieldLogicalName] = recordFieldValue.Length < stringAttributeMetadata.MaxLength.Value ?  recordFieldValue : recordFieldValue.Substring(0,stringAttributeMetadata.MaxLength.Value - 1);
```